Dynamically growing data structure, like Java's arraylist
I have a usecase wherein I am reading streaming data from server, and putting it into an array. So my approach is:
var points = str.split("\n"); //split input based on new line character
var positions = new Float32Array();
for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  var coords = points[i].split("_"); //split line into individual values separated by '_'
  for(let j=0; j < coords.length; j++) {
      var coord = parseFloat(coords[j]) // parse string to float
      positions.push(coord); // add to float array
  }
}

But this is not working. code execution just stops at 'push', and nothing happens after that.
Is Float32Array not correct data structure for this usecase?

Float32Arrays do not grow and do not have a push method. Just use a regular Array.

So another part of the issue is that API I am using needs typed array. Can normal js Array be typed?

You can convert it to a typed array afterwards. Or you determine the required size up front.

Typed arrays don't have a push method. Instead just populate a standard array and then pass that to the Float32Array constructor. You could also use some array methods here, like map and flatMap:


// Example input
const str = `12.0_0.5
-2.25_8.5
3.5_16.0`;

const positions = new Float32Array(
    str.split("\n").flatMap(point => point.split("_").map(Number))
);
console.log(positions);




The error is happen because you're not initialize the size of array. You can change that code to my recommendations.
var points = str.split("\n"); // split input based on new line character
var totalCoords = points.length * points[0].split("_").length; // calculate total number of coordinates
var positions = new Float32Array(totalCoords); // initialize Float32Array with the correct length

var index = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  var coords = points[i].split("_"); // split line into individual values separated by '_'
  for (let j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
    var coord = parseFloat(coords[j]); // parse string to float
    positions[index++] = coord; // assign to the correct index in Float32Array
  }
}

Or you can just simple change Float32Array to basic array.
var points = str.split("\n"); // split input based on new line character
var tempArray = []; // initialize a basic array

for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  var coords = points[i].split("_"); // split line into individual values separated by '_'
  for (let j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
    var coord = parseFloat(coords[j]); // parse string to float
    tempArray.push(coord); // add to basic array
  }
}

